# Pass JSON from Javascript to Rust-compiled WebAssembly as HashMap

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

How could I pass a JSON object from JS to a Rust function? Must all JSON objects with key value pairs be serialised before passing it in a call to an exported function from the compiled WASM? (Just primitive types, strings or integers for example)

Functions can be called passing a string easily, with Rust on the receiving end expecting a `&str` type. However, I can't figure out how I might specify the type for a JSON object. Using `HashMap<&str, &str>` results in an error with `wasm-bindgen`, with the message as follows:

```
the trait `wasm_bindgen::convert::FromWasmAbi` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>`
```

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2341) for this. I think your best bet is to take a `JsValue` and convert it by hand. It doesn't look like you could implement `FromWasmAbi` for some wrapper yourself, because there's no appropriate [`WasmAbi`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2.79/wasm_bindgen/convert/trait.FromWasmAbi.html#associatedtype.Abi) type.

Comment: @Caesar I'm not quite clear on how you convert a JsValue by hand, is this with `js_sys::Iterator`? Otherwise sounds like `wasm-bindgen` is already serialising JSON object to some u32 array first to make a `JsValue`, so I imagine would be equivalent to any other serialisation / deserialisation strategy?

Comment: Hm, you're right. And if you're at that point, `JsValue::into_serde::<HashMap<String, String>>` is probably more convenient.

Comment: Thanks - if you like you can add that as an answer. For serialisation I'm planning to look into Cap n' Proto (capnp crate), which advertises no overhead for serialisation / deserialisation.